# Why doesn't my dired+ configuration of default applications through dired-guess-shell-alist-user work?

Tags: dired

I'd like to configure `dired+` to use default applications and read that I should put these configurations into the `dired-guess-shell-alist-user` variable. I've tried a few variations but, even though I've checked that the variable is set to the configuration I've put in, `dired+` always just opens the files as textfiles. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the configuration as it is currently in my .emacs file:

```lisp
(require 'dired-x)

(setq dired-guess-shell-alist-user
      '(("\\.mp3" "mplayer -af scaletempo")
        ("\\.mkv" "mplayer")))
```

Comment: I just filed bug #[62126](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=62126), to have the doc mention option `dired-guess-shell-alist-user`.

Comment: You don't say what problem you see with using the above code. You don't say what Dired command you tried. Did you try just using `!` or `&`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is how it is supposed to work since it's nowhere clearly written, but I found that if I don't open the files but run `diredp-shell-command-this-file`, then it does what it's supposed to do. I've now bound the command, which isn't bound to any key at all, to E, which was free, and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how it's supposed to work. But even just `!` and `&` should also work.